# Splitting a string on special characters

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, split

I have a string of an undefined amount of elements separated by `~~`, eg:

```
foobar~~some example text~~this is a string
```

How can I split these values into a simple array which I can then loop through?

I was trying to replace the `~~` with commas with a regex so I could then work on it as a csv but there must be an easier way?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method

```
var str = "foobar~~some example text~~this is a string";
var arr = str.split('~~');
$.each(arr,function(indx,val){
   console.log(val);
});
```

Or you can acess like `arr[0]`,`arr[1]`,`arr[2]` ....

Ouptput

```
   "foobar"
   "some example text"
   "this is a string"
```

Answer (score 0):

use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)

```
string str = "foobar~~some example text~~this is a string";
string[] _result = str.Split("~~", StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `Split` method. You could do the following:

```
string[] arr=yourString.Split("~~");
foreach(string arrElement in arr)
{
   //do what ever you want to
}
```